# Intellij gui bugs on manjaro

Tags: intellij-idea, window-resize

I'm using manjaro since a wil, and everything is well else intellij.
the size and ratio of tool bar and side bars is unacceptable.
I tried to resize tool bar but the resize button in (window -> active tool window) is disabled, and I tried to find anything could helps in settings but nothing relatd to ui is working (for example background opacity).

[image]

as shown in the picture I couldn't work clean with the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have more space for code, you can try one of the following:

1. Change the [IDE view mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-viewing-modes.html) via View > Appearance to the one that fits your purpose the best.
2. In usual mode hide all the side windows with Hide tool windows (Ctrl+Shift+F12).
3. Show / Hide any components via View > Appearance, that is, check/uncheck toolbar, Navigation bar, etc.
4. Decrease IDE font size (Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance, Use custom font) and/or Editor font size (Settings | Editor | Font).

If none of the suggested options works for you, please file a [new issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) in our tracker and describe what exactly goes wrong in your case if you follow this or that suggestion. Thank you!